# Optional return type: Attempting to use incompatible return type

Tags: java, generics

Error:

```
'get()' in 'test.B' clashes with 'get()' in 'test.A'; attempting to use incompatible return type
```

The code is as follows, how to fix it? Thanks!

```java
interface A {

    Optional<A> get() ;

}

interface B extends A {

    @Override
    Optional<B> get();
}
```

Comment: `Optional<B>` is not an `Optional<A>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to generify `A` and bind the generic parameter to be a subclass of `A`.

```
interface A<S extends A<S>> {

  Optional<S> get() ;
}
```

Now `B` is declared to return optional of `B`:

```
interface B extends A<B> {

  @Override
  Optional<B> get();
}
```

Note that overriding `get()` is redundant, because `B extends A<B>` the method is already returning `Optional<B>`.

Keep in mind this won't stop you from having a `C`, which returns an optional of `B`.

```
interface C extends A<B> {

  @Override
  Optional<B> get();
}
```

Comment: A sealed interface can prevent you from having `C`.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle The problem is not having a `C`, but that `C` is returning `Optional<B>` (sealed can't handle this). It's unclear, if this behaviour is desired, so I am warning OP about it.

Comment: Is it possible to only do something on method `get()` without going to generify class `A`?

Comment: @Bourbon_7 You could change the return type to `Optional<? extends A> get();`, but then you can do `class Test3 implements A` with method - `public Optional<B> get() {}`.